# Ruby - comparação de valores entre um range ou maior que, menor que

Tags: ruby, case, range

Estou começando a estudar programação então, vai uma pergunta bem de iniciante.

Fiz o teste abaixo para aprender sobre `case` em *Ruby*,

```
current_time = ARGV.first.to_i

case current_time
when 0..45 then puts('First Haf')
when 46..90 then puts('Second Haf')
else puts('Invalid Time')
end
```

Tudo ia bem até que tentei explorar um pouco mais o código, exibindo avisos para tempos maiores que `90` ou menor que `-1` e aí tudo parou.

Segue o código que deu problema

```
current_time = ARGV.first.to_i

case current_time
when 0..45 then puts('First Haf')
when 46..90 then puts('Second Haf')
when > 91 then puts('Overtime')
when < -1 then puts('Game not started')
else puts('Invalid Time')
end
```

A mensagem exibida no console é

> ```
> ruby case2-range-tempo-futebol.rb 91
> case2-range-tempo-futebol.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected '>'
> when > 91 then puts('Overtime')
>       ^
> case2-range-tempo-futebol.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting end-of-input
> when < -1 then puts('Game not star
> ```

Caso alguém saiba como ajudar, desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não entendo muito de ruby, mas por uma rápida lida acredito que seja por escapar a comparação ao infinito, tanto pra negativo como para positivo.

O comparador `-Float::INFINITY...0` parece indicar para comparar se o numero é negativo.

E para escapar para positivo, use a saida final do else, e faça mais um if dentro dele, como no exemplo a baixo:

```
tempo = -4
case tempo
when -Float::INFINITY...0 then puts 'Jogo nao iniciado'
when 0..45 then puts 'Primeiro tempo'
when 46..90 then puts 'Segundo tempo'
else 
  if tempo >= 91
    puts 'Tempo finalizado'
  else
    puts 'Tempo invalido'
  end
end
```

Veja funcionando no fiddle: [AQUI](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/f8828)

Referencias:

[Ruby range: operators in case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065244/ruby-range-operators-in-case-statement)

[Infinity in Ruby](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-infinity/)

Comment: Muito obrigado AnthraxisBR! Valeu pela ajuda!

Answer (score 4):

A resposta do [@AnthraxisBR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277359/41056) funciona bem, mas gostaria de estendê-la explicando por que funciona.

A comparação `when > 10` não funciona pois uma expressão precisa de dois lados. O `when` espera um valor para comparar, e não o próprio comparador.

A ideia de usar um [`Range`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html) é fantástica e funciona muito bem quando você precisa comparar se um valor está entre um intervalo. **E ele funciona pois o `Range` implementa o método `===`, chamado de *case equality*.**

Abra o IRB e teste as expressões utilizando o *case equality*. Você terá que:

```
irb(main):001:0> (1..10) === 5
=> true
irb(main):002:0> (1..10) === 11
=> false
```

Inspecionando o que o `===` faz no `Range`, descobri que o que ele faz é chamar o método `include?`. É escrito em C.

```
range_eqq(VALUE range, VALUE val)
{
    return rb_funcall(range, rb_intern("include?"), 1, val);
}
```

Pode-se dizer que `Range#===` é um alias para `Range#include?`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação @vnbrs!